# runtime error(nzec) in python

Tags: python-2.7, runtime-error

It works fin in my pc and in an online compiler+debugger. However, when I submit it in codechef, it gives me a runtime error(nzec). When do you get a runtime error and how to you resolve it. What is the problem in this code? I keep getting runtime error very frequently. How do I avoid it? Any kind of help will be deeply appreciated!

```
t = int(raw_input())
for i in range(t):
    a = map(int, raw_input())
    if a.index(min(a)) != 0: 
        if min(a) == 0:
            print a.index(min(a))
        else:
            print str(str(a.index(min(a))) * (min(a)+1))
    elif a.index(min(a)) == 0:
        k = min(a)
        a[0] = 99
        l = min(a)
        if l == k:
            print str(str(a.index(min(a))) * min(a))
        elif l > k:
            print '1'+ ('0' * (k+1))
```

Comment: why do you post the same [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17373344/nzec-runtime-error-in-python) twice?

Comment: well... I am never able to find out the correct reason for a run time error...the earlier one was for a different code... and this is a different code.

Comment: Hope my answer helps you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to split the `raw_input()`

`raw_input()` receives the input as just a string. Use `raw_input().split()` to convert the string to a list. Else you will have indexing problems, since the spaces given in the input are taken for mapping. So you get the **nzec** (non-zero exit code) error

```
a=map(int,raw_input().split())
```

will do

Answer (score 2):

Many times it is due to some white places left.

Try this:

```
raw_input().strip().split(" ")
```

if the data is separated by " ".